# Why is the left / right sequence important in conductor solution to philosophers dinner?

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, deadlock, semaphore, dining-philosopher

The conductor solution to the philosopher dinner problem as described suggest that a semphore of size four be used and that all philosophers attempt to get left fork before right fork. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem#Conductor_solution

It also suggests that philosophers pick up forks in left / right sequence?

Why is important that philosopher pick up forks in left / right sequence?

Or all in the same sequence (I guess they can all be right / left too)?

Answer (score 1):

Deadlock typically happens when you have an order issue with your locks, for example:

```
Thread 1: acquire lock1 then lock2
Thread 2: acquire lock2 then lock1
```

If T1 manages to acquire lock1 andT2 to acquire lock2 simultaneously, they are both blocked and you have a deadlock.

By introducing a specific order, for example: lock1 must always be acquire before lock2, you remove the problem:

```
Thread 1: acquire lock1 then lock2
Thread 2: acquire lock1 then lock2
```

As soon as T1 acquires lock1, T2 is unable to make progress and to acquire lock2, which remains available for T1.

Imposing a left first then right sequence achieves the same objective and simplifies the role of the conductor.

Answer (score 0):

First - it says that the sequence has to be left/right or right/left for all philosophers.

It all depends on the additional subtle assumptions. I think that in the "conductor solution" to the problem the sequence left/right is not really important if we assume that the waiter is smart enough. If the waiter is aware of the whole table situation he could grant the forks in a "conservative" way so that the deadlock couldn't occur - that would be a centralized solution.
The fixed sequence helps the conductor to decide if the fork can be granted because the philosophers act in more predictable way.